# Why is connection refused by Vagrant box in Windows 10?

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualbox, windows-10

I've been having problems with Vagrant since upgrading to Windows 10. At first I had the ["host-only adapter" problem](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6068) that many people seem to be experiencing. This was fixed by updating VirtualBox to the latest version, and my Vagrant box now seems to provision and start ok, and I can SSH into it, but can't connect via HTTP. If I try to access it from a browser, I get "Unable to connect". If I try `curl`ing it, I get the message:

```
Failed to connect to test.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

I've checked and Apache seems to be running on the VM (and in fact if I SSH into the VM and then run `curl 127.0.0.1` the expected homepage is returned). At this point I've drawn a blank: I don't know whether the problem is in Windows or the VM's settings. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(For what it's worth, I'm using VirtualBox 5.0.15r105158 + Vagrant 1.8.1)

**Update**: it turns out that the VM *is* accessible from `test.dev:8888` in the browser, so I'm guessing the problem is to do with port-forwarding? I don't know much about this though, so have no idea why this wouldn't be working in Windows 10. (In case it helps, my Vagrantfile contains the line `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered all by yourself - you might read the vagrant doc on [port forwarding](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html)

> Vagrant forwarded ports allow you to access a port on your host
> machine and have all data forwarded to a port on the guest machine,
> over either TCP or UDP.
>
> For example: If the guest machine is running a web server listening on
> port 80, you can make a forwarded port mapping to port 8888 (or
> anything) on your host machine. You can then open your browser to
> localhost:8888 and browse the website, while all actual network data
> is being sent to the guest.

when you add the line `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888` to your vagrant file, the VM (i.e. call also guest or guest VM) )will forward all the stream going on its port 80 to the host (in you case the windows machine) on port 8888, so in this case when you point your browser to listen on port 8888 you can see the website running from the VM

When you are within the VM though, you point to the expected 80 port.

one additional point (hope not to confuse you): in your Vagrantfile, did you define something for networking ? (param `config.vm.network`) you probably define a fixed IP (since you point to test.dev) in such case you dont need to do port forwarding, you can correctly access `http://test.dev` (on default port 80) as nothing else is bounding to this port. Port forwarding is really useful when you use public network and you do not define a fix IP to the guest VM, so in this case you access the site running on the VM from localhost/127.0.0.1, and as such you cannot just point to port 80, as something on your host can already be running.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I've set a private network in my Vagrantfile too, and have the relevant line in my hosts file, giving the VM a fixed IP (starting with 192.168). Before upgrading to Windows 10, I was able to access the VM at `http://test.dev` exactly as you describe, but now I'm not (I have to access `test.dev:8888` instead). I haven't touched the hosts file or the Vagrantfile. I don't know enough about networking to quite understand where the problem is likely to lie.

Comment: did you have the port forwarding before ? as said if you use private networking, you dont need it

Comment: Yes, I've always had that with no problem (and I use more-or-less this Vagrantfile on other machines, both Windows 8.1 and OSX, with no problem) - the only change has been the upgrade to Windows 10. If I remove that port-forwarding line (`config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8888`) from my Vagrantfile then *neither* `http://test.dev` *nor* `http://test.dev:8888` work.